# Aligning multiple "decimal points" in table column (by expanding one column into multiple?)

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, columns, xparse, collcell

I'm working a document with values that have multiple "decimal points" (historical units & currencies) and am trying to create a column type that can align these properly (like `siunitx` does for single decimal points).

The values may come from macros or via `csvsimple`, and I would eventually like to sum them automatically (I have code that can do this, but it is excised here for brevity). I also intend to make the number of cells arbitrary.

I've tried using `collcell` and `xparse` to expand a cell's contents into 3 cells, but unfortunately it does not work (it throws `Misplaced alignment tab character &` errors). I suspect it has to do with expansion rules...?

MWE (broken):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\dms@get@values@internal[3]{%
    \edef\dms@value@A{#1}%
    \edef\dms@value@B{#2}%
    \edef\dms@value@C{#3}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand\dms@make@cells{ > {\SplitArgument { 2 } { . } } m }{%
    %\show#1%
    \dms@get@values@internal#1%
    \dms@value@A{}% Rdl%
    &% <- "Misplaced alignment tab character &" error here
    \dms@value@B{}% mrk%
    &% <- and here
    \dms@value@C{}% skl%
}

\newcolumntype{E}[1]{%
    % #1 = number of fields (TODO)
    >{\collectcell\dms@make@cells}%
    r%
    <{\endcollectcell}%
    @{.}%
    r%
    @{.}%
    r%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ r  E{3}  l }
    \toprule
    First & Rdl.mrk.skl & Last \\
    \midrule
    test & 1.2.3 & test \\
    test & 10.20.30 & test \\
    %test & 2.4.5\nicefrac{3/4} & test \\ % this breaks entirely
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: never use tabularx without an X column, just use tabular here.

Comment: Sorry, that was from an earlier revision. Thanks for spotting. I'll update the MWE